Pixel size and Fourier domain
I'm developing an off-axis digital holographic camera. Initially, I employed a CCD camera with 6.7-micrometer pixels and successfully observed the first-order interference pattern in the Fourier domain. However, when I switched to a CCD camera with smaller pixels (1.67 micrometers), the first-order pattern vanished. Can you explain why this occurred?
